# navigation carlike

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to use the navigation stack in a carlike robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12096/navigation-carlike/) by [kleber](https://answers.ros.org/users/1443/kleber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/27/how-can-i-use-the-navigation-stack-on-a-carlike

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2